# Spring Boot: Inject bean before another from library

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, environment-variables, javabeans

I have a Spring Boot app in which the company has developed a library that has been developed in the worst way (but I cannot control that). This library uses environment variables for the configuration so it is annoying having to declare these environment variables to make the app run locally, let's say it has been this way:

This is a web filter:

```java
private void checkEnvironmentVariables() {
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(System.getProperty(LibraryEnvConfNames.ENV_1)))             
        throw new Exception(System.getProperty(LibraryEnvConfNames.ENV_1));
    if (StringUtils.isBlank(System.getProperty(LibraryEnvConfNames.ENV_2)))
        throw new Exception(System.getProperty(LibraryEnvConfNames.ENV_2));
}
```

For `dev` and `qa` environments there are no problems because these env variables are injected with a config map that is already configured but for new developers and normal people, to run it locally it is so annoying having to declare all these environment variables in IntelliJ, Eclipse or whatever.

I am trying to make within each app a configuration bean class that before this code will be executed it will inject random properties for local development (because actually for local development it does not matter the values of these variables).

```java
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
@ConditionalOnExpression("'${spring.profiles.active}'.equals('local')")
public class LocalRequestFilterConfig {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger( LocalRequestFilterConfig.class);

    @Bean
    public void inyectLocalEnvVariables(){
        LOGGER.info( "Injecting local variables configuration" );
        System.setProperty( "ENV_1","TEST" );
        System.setProperty( "ENV_2","test" );
    }
}
```

The point is that I don't know how may I manage the order of these beans' initialization. I can not add a `dependsOn` because it is from an external library and I don't know how to make my configuration being injected before the initialization of the filter in the library.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you could possibly achieve this is with XML configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="beanOnOtherLib" class="com.whatever.BeanOnOtherLib" depends-on="localRequestFilterConfig"/>
    <bean id="localRequestFilterConfig" class="com.whatever.LocalRequestFilterConfig"/>
</beans>
```

But to be honest I never mixed XML and annotation-based configurations so I am not really sure this could work. Nevertheless, it is the only way I am thinking on given that you can't change the code in the other lib.

Comment: Where should I add this XML?

Comment: It should be named `beans.xml` and usually, it is placed neat `application.yml`, but with `@ImportResource` you can specify where it is. Additional details: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-xml-beans.

Comment: Ok Joao I will try that and I will let you know if it works or not. Thanks, by the way I love baeldung! XD

Comment: It did not work :( or at least I have not been able to do it